# Need to apply geometry node animation for GLB Export

Tags: animation, export, geometry-nodes

I'm looking to morph from a smooth model to voxel. I know it is possible to do this with modifiers and geo nodes but exporting for .GLB (for web) will only export the first frame of the animation as it 'applies' the modifiers.

Is it possible to bake or convert a geo node or modifier animation so that I can morph from smooth to voxel?

Comment: i assume you would have to bake every keyframe to do that. so on frame 1 > apply geometry nodes -> then keyframe your result, then repeat that steps for all keyframes.

Comment: How about Alembic (.abc) format, is it a viable format for your purpose? It can nicely store the geo nodes animation using [MeshSequenceCache modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/mesh_sequence_cache.html).

Comment: I think it's not possible to do it manually per keyframe for complex geometry nodes animations. I'm trying to do it with my geo plant-to-tree animation. [Here they discouraged using Geometry Nodes](https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/sdi5b1/how_to_export_geometry_nodes_based_animation_from/) if you need to export the animation.